# Доступ к адресу сервера через ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте, javascript, mysql

Допустим,я создал приложение в ВК, и БД лежит на удаленном сервере. Вопрос, можно ли как то вычислить по какому адресу приложение работает с БД.

Нужно проверить одну идею, если так взять, то нужно будет сначало контакт взломать(что почти нереально) а потом выследить куда приложение отправляет данные.

Таким способом это будет очень безопасный способ. Или же можно вычислить напрямую куда приложение отправляет, что не безопасно.

**Суть в том,** что бы доказать, что создав приложение вконтакте, я. можно сказать, получаю такую же степень защиты как и сам контакт, ибо пока контакт не взломают, ***доступ к адресу приложения не получат или получат? Таким способом не смогут найти адрес где лежит БД приложения***

Comment: В чём проблема для начала взять какой-нибудь Wireshark да посмотреть трафик? Впрочем, почему "какой-то", его и взять... :-)

Comment: Спасибо, посмеялся.

Все зависит от того, как приложение работает с бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идёт об [iframe или flash приложении](https://vk.com/dev/native), то запросы идут из браузера клиента, т.е. любой инструмент покажет, откуда загружен iframe: FireBug, Developer tools.

Схемы, в которой VK выступал бы в качестве прокси, прикрывая бэкенд автора приложения, я не знаю.